# GitLab 7.9.1 : Attachment on Wiki is not pointing to the correct port.

Tags: gitlab, wiki

I have installed GitLab 7.9.1 Omnibus on a server which is already running Apache. So, I have changed the external_url in the gitlab.rb to the following to avoid conflict:

```
external_url 'http://example.gitlab.com:9000'
```

The webpage example.gitlab.com:9000 works perfectly fine. I can create projects, add users, manage wiki, etc...

The only issue that i'm having is when I drag an attachment in the Wiki, a link is incorrectly generated

```
[file.pdf](http://example.gitlab.com/user/repo/uploads/9aff2385543d9fcb7e7caf9755d4a554/file.pdf)
```

The document is successfully uploaded but it cannot be retrieved unless I  modify the attachment link and add the port 9000.

Although it is a small process, I want to avoid doing this everytime. Which file do I modify in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you check in the `gitlab-shell` conf file (/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml) the value of `gitlab_url` parameter ? It's default value is `http://localhost:8080/` and it's not updated when you change it in `gitlab.rb`